# Selecting certain rows of two huge matrices

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two huge matrices m1 and m2 (length 25000), and for simplicity let us assume they are:

```
m1 = {{1, 1, -56}, {1.3, 2, 3.06}, {2, 0, -30.02}, {3, 
   1, -7.291}, {3.5, 2, 1.93}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}, {5.5, 
   1, -356.4}, {6, 1, 9.945}, {7, 0, -7.512}};
m2 = {{1, 1, -56}, {1, 2, 3.06} + .2, {2, 
0, -30.02}, {3, 1, -7.291} + .3, {3, 2, 1.93}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 
0}, {5, 1, -356.4} + .4, {6, 1, 9.945}, {7, 0, -7.512}};
```

I wrote the following code with the help of this forum to pick those rows of both matrices that have the same first value. However, the code is very slow

```
picker1 = m1[[All, 1]];
picker2 = m2[[All, 1]];
newM1 = Cases[m1, x_ /; MemberQ[picker2, x[[1]]]]
newM2 = Cases[m2, x_ /; MemberQ[picker1, x[[1]]]]
```

I know the code is not an efficient and  I appreciate if you can help me with  more efficient and fast code.

Comment: `Pick[m1, MemberQ[picker2, #] & /@ picker1]` and 
`Pick[m2, MemberQ[picker1, #] & /@ picker2]`?

Comment: qahtah, your application could be boosted immensely if you can achieve to have matrices with either all integers or all real numbers, so that they can be packed. However, `MemberQ` has certain problems with floating point numbers. Do the first entries in each row in your huge matrices happen to be integers?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher no they are real.

Comment: @kglr too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `MemberQ` is not a good idea, performancewise.

Let's create some example data

```
n = 25000;
m = 1000;
p1 = RandomInteger[{1, m}, n];
p2 = RandomInteger[{1, m}, n];
a1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
a2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
```

Note that we separated the "pickers" `p1` and `p2` from the data `a1`, `a2`. So `m1[[i]]` would correspond to `Join[{p1[[i]]},a1[[i]]]`. This way, `p1`, `p2`, `a1`, and `a2` are all [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/38178).

For each list of pickers `p1`, `p2`, I create an `Association` with values all `1`.

```
dict1 = AssociationThread[p1, 1];
dict2 = AssociationThread[p2, 1];
```

This way, `dict1[x]` will return `1` (read as `True`) if `x` is a member of `p1` and `Missing["KeyAbsent", x]` otherwise. `Lookup` can convert `Missing[...]` to a default value; we use `0` (read as `False`) in the following. We create new lists of pickers `newp1` and `newp2` along with the new data matrices `newa1` and `newa2`:

```
With[{b1 = Developer`ToPackedArray[Lookup[dict2, p1, 0]]},
   newp1 = Pick[p1, b1, 1];
   newa1 = Pick[a1, b1, 1];
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming
With[{b2 = Developer`ToPackedArray[Lookup[dict1, p2, 0]]},
   newp2 = Pick[p2, b2, 1];
   newa2 = Pick[a2, b2, 1];
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> 0.002823
>
> 0.002927

Here, we use `Pick` with `1` as third argument to pick all rows from `a1` for which the corresponding entry in `b1` is 1. 
Doing the anologous by constructions involving `MemberQ` takes about `5` seconds on my machine.

One has to be careful if the pickers are floating point numbers: This construction with `Association` might break down due to rounding errors since `Association`s are very literal about the keys. But that's the same with `MemberQ`.

Comment: Thanks. The first values of rows are distinct. It works very well.